# See which Textfield is empty

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm working on my school project. I have a Student Registration form. So when I entered the student details and by pressing the "Save" button, I can save the details to the database. But I need to validate all the jTextfields so that if the user accidentally have not inserted a detail (let's say his last name) I need to stop saving the data into the database on "Save" button clicking. And if the user has forgot to enter several details (like middle name, street address, gender) I need to show an error saying these jTextfields are empty and you need to insert data into them.

I specifically need to tell which Textfield is causing the error. not as a whole or publicly "You have an Error" but I need to tell the user that these Text fields are causing the error and you need to insert data onto them.

Comment: someone please help me :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You probably should use `TextInputLayout` for showing error. It's my point. About your question. It isn't correct, because you should ask about some specific issue and show us your code. Community won't do homework for you.

Comment: @Beloo : yes you are right, but I cannot even think about a single code though

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the conditions in a `if` statement and then print out your message. Add this to your `save` button code.
Try something like this :

```
    if(jFeild.getText().equals("")) { //or your condition which validates it
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(yourFrame, "message you want to display");
   }
```

The rest you can implement it by yourself, I think you get the idea of what to do.

Comment: Well, at least I got you started. I would suggest making a class that validates all the information or method that does it and returns the one which are invalid.